# What do we call someone who does not like to gossip?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the one-word description of someone who avoids gossips(listening and spreading as well)?
Specifically, not a recluse, but a sincere and practical person who believes in realistic-facts and not dramatic, sensational but trivial stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several candidates. Here are four:

> Reserved =
> Reserved people do not often talk about or show their feelings or thoughts:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restrained?q=Reserved)

> Reserved = restrained in words and actions
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reserved)

> Reticent = unwilling to speak about your thoughts or feelings
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restrained?q=Reticent)

> Taciturn = tending not to speak much:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restrained?q=Taciturn)

> Restrained = acting in a calm and controlled way
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restrained?q=Restrained+)

Of these, I would normally use **reserved** because it seems to include the qualities of the other three. A reserved person may be taciturn, restrained, reticent, or any combination of the three.

Answer (score 1):

> who believes in realistic-facts and not dramatic, sensational but trivial stories

**grounded** might fit here:

*—used to describe a person who is sensible and has a good understanding of what is really important in life* (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: I can't find the page. If you are referring to this, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grounded, then it says about someone who is mentally and emotionally stable, more like phlegmatic. That doesn't align much with the one who hates telltales.

Comment: @Trusha_Patel Scroll down for more definitions there.

Comment: @bobcat- Sorry. Nevertheless, I believe this applies more to someone who is realistic, for instance, a down-to-earth celebrity, who understands that fame and limelight are temporary and faux, but nothing about gossips. So it makes up for a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could call such a person **Staid**

> Characterized by sedateness and often a strait-laced sense of propriety; serious and conventional.

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Another good choice would be **Sobersides**

> A serious and sedate individual

*But he was never a rapscallion ripstitch— Always a prim and proper little man, A butter-won’t-melt-in-my-mouth young sobersides, Since he found his own feet.*

[Vocabulary.com]